# C++/CLI/C# BadImageFormat Exception when loading form

Tags: c#, c++-cli, wrapper

I created a C++/CLI assembly that creates a wrapper around native C++ code.  The resource compiles and the assembly loads fine into my C# project when I add it as a resource. I can access my objects and intellisense from within my application, but when attempting to build, it crashes with the exception:

**BadImageFormat**

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'MyCLI, Version=1.0.3680.28432,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>   or one of its dependencies. An attempt
>   was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format.

I load it into my form load event:

```
MyCLI.myCLI z;
```

... and when I compile, it crashes on this line in my main constructor in C#

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Does anyone have an idea of what could be causing this exception?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to run this code on a 64-bit operating system.  Your C# code will get nicely compiled to 64-bit machine code.  But you'll hit the wall when it tries to load a 32-bit C++/CLI assembly.

In the C# project, use Project + Properties, Application tab, Platform Target = x86.  Creating a 64-bit version of your C++/CLI assembly is possible too, use Build + Configuration Manager.  Using Platform Target is the better solution.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure that's it now that you pointed it out -- however, I cannot get my C++/CLI project to show anything else than Win32 and my C# project has the platform target dropdown disabled.  Also note I am on a 64 bit operating system

Comment: Disabled?  That's *very* strange.  You can use Corflags.exe to do the same.  Re-run VS setup to get the 64-bit C/C++ compiler, it is not installed by default.

Comment: If you would like to compile a C++ project to x64, you need to read through some articles, such as this one, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2k70f3s(VS.80).aspx

Comment: In Visual Studio 2008 the platform target is on the Build tab, make sure you change the one in the tab itself, not the Configuration target at the top.