# Invoke C++/CLI code from C#

Tags: c#, visual-c++, .net-3.5, c++-cli, interop

There are two projects (C# and Managed C++). C# projects needs to call a method in ManagedCPP project. in reference section of c# project the managed cpp dll is added.

if Line 1, 2 and 3 are uncommented and Line 4 is commented, then also following problem occurs:

> Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException

The code base is as follows:

`C# class:`

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using ManagedCPP;

namespace CSharp
{
class Program
{
    //[DllImport("ManagedCPP")]                   // Line 1
    //public static extern void Convert();        // Line 2

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().CreateObject();
    }

    private void CreateObject()
    {
        //Convert();                              // Line 3
        ManagedCPPEntryClass c = new ManagedCPPEntryClass();  // Line 4

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

`C++/CLI class(.h):`

```
namespace ManagedCPP 
{
public ref class ManagedCPPEntryClass
{
    public:
        void Convert();
};
}
```

`C++/CLI class(.cpp):`

```
#include "ManagedCPP.h"
using namespace ManagedCPP;

void ManagedCPPEntryClass::Convert()
{
}
```

Comment: See the documentation for `BadImageFormatException` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx

Comment: I changed the platform target of C# project from Any CPU to x86 and it's working now. but what was the issue. does c++/cli compiles to x86 only as i didn't see any option to configure the target platform for c++/cli project.

Comment: why not just add a .net reference to the output assembly from the C++/CLI project and leave P/Invoke out of it? You don't appear to be controlling your marshaling or anything like that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your native code (C++) is compiled with the same format (32 bits or 64 bits) as the .Net execution format of your C# application(32 bits or 64 bits again). This may be the cause of your problem.

By default .Net executes itself in the same format as the OS. You can force execution in a chosen format by setting a compilation option in visual studio.

Comment: I changed the platform target of C# project from `Any CPU` to `x86` and it's working now. but what was the issue. does c++/cli compiles to `x86` only as i didn't see any option to configure the target platform for c++/cli project.

Comment: it's possible. described here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159494/c-cli-c-badimageformat-exception-when-loading-form

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on the topic, but you should use DllImport to access a non-CLI assembly, while a CLI can be directly used in C# as if it were a native assembly (the advantage of using a common interface).

Answer (score 1):

Commented lines are used to call unmamaged API Convert from unmanaged Dll IPF_ManagedCPP. Actually, IPF_ManagedCPP is managed Dll, and Convert is managed class method. Of course, this cannot work.

C++/CLI class library should be used by client .NET code exactly like any other class library. Unmanaged Dll can be used in .NET project by two ways: using PInvoke or using C++/CLI wrapper. You don't need PInvoke for IPF_ManagedCPP library.